# sorting in case mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM case_study
ORDER BY CASE 

WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 3 

WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL  THEN 2

WHEN expiry_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 1 

END DESC
```

The above query work's fine, But i want to sort the `items` by expiry date in ASC in one case and DESC in one case.How to acheive this it should be some thing like this

***pseudo query***

```
WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 3 expiry_date_case ASC

WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL  THEN 2

WHEN expiry_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 1 expiry_date_case DESC
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more generic form of doing the sorting, where you can use multiple conditions for ordering other than date

```
SELECT *
FROM case_study
ORDER BY 
 CASE 
   WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 3 
   WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL  THEN 2
   WHEN expiry_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 1 
END DESC,
case when expiry_date_case > CURDATE() then expiry_date_case end,
case when expiry_date_case < CURDATE() then expiry_date_case end desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM case_study
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 3 
            WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL  THEN 2
            WHEN expiry_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 1 
         END DESC,
         ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), expiry_date_case))
```

All records:

1. having `expiry_date_case` *past* `CURDATE()` will come first,
2. then come `NULL` records, followed by,
3. records having `expiry_date_case < CURDATE()`.

Group `[1]` records will be in ascending order (within their own group), whereas group `[3]` records will be in descending order.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4656/6)